# Is there enough synergy in different race combinations to justify a race switch when playing 2v2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I prefer playing as zerg generally, although I do a fair amount of "random", but I've recently started playing 2v2 with a friend who's also a zerg player, and I have been considering switching to playing terran, simply for the synergy of medivacs and zerg, but also to offer up a few more options when dealing with issues like stealth, air, drops, early rushes, etc.

I would like to keep my question focused, and also widely applicable, so my primary question is: will switching to T/Z give us an edge in 2v2 over Z/Z assuming I'm almost as good at Terran as I am as Zerg?

But some secondary questions I wouldn't mind getting feedback on are:

1. What Z/Z synergies might we be losing?  I'm specifically thinking of the benefit of having 2 people producing creep instead of 1.
2. is it a good idea in general to choose races in 2v2 based on race synergies?
3. what other race combos have interesting synergies/strategies?

Comment: I am expecting tzenes to post an amazing answer

Comment: lol, same.  Something thesis-worthy.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I can't provide the correct answer to this question without getting drawn into the "Is 2v2 Balanced" debate.  We had the same thing back during Broodwars.

Comment: @tzenes sorry to throw that fly in your ointment.  Seems a sore spot.  but 1v1 is so.......lonely.  2v2 is much more social, win or lose.  at least at the bronze/silver level

Comment: @Hurrikane its ok.  The world is an imperfect place.

Comment: I am just socked I got an accepted answer on Starcraft 2 question

Comment: @Elpez hehe, i know how you feel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Race synergies are important but it is more important for players to have a strong synergy. I would focus less on race and more on player strategy. It all comes back to play style. For example the z/z race combination has a very strong 12 pool rush for example.

My partner and I play p/t, with a focus on 4 warpgate for me and armor for him. We try to divvy up early, middle, and late game focus. For example as the protoss player, may goal is to 4 warpgate ASAP while provide scouting and early resource harassment. The mid-game is dominated by my Terran player focus on tanks and air support (depending on opponents). End game focus is on void rays/ Terran air-superiority combos and other "higher tech units" In essence, as the protoss player I am more focus on micro and my partner is focused on macro.

Comment: Mind explaining what you mean by "we try to divvy up early, middle and late game focus" ?

Comment: @Hurrikane, there you go

Comment: very interesting.  Some replays would be sweet to see if you have any to post.

Comment: also please tell me the secret code i have to enter to build wraiths!! :)

Comment: @Hurrikane, if you would like some replays, my friend and I are high diamond 2v2 random players, so I should either have saved, or can get replays of any race match-up.

Answer (score 4):

For your main question, I agree that **player synergy trumps race synergy**. If you are most comfortable (and skilled) playing Zerg, then play Zerg. Smart play and good coordination with your teammate will serve you better than trying to use clever unit tricks with a race you don't like as much and don't play as well with.

As for other race combos, here's some **Terran/Protoss Synergies:**

- Defense: Supply Depot "drawbridge" and Bunkers can protect Protoss teching to Void Rays etc
- Economy: Gas-light Terran builds can give gas to Protoss air builds
- Economy: Protoss can give minerals to Terran, where it's converted directly into Marines
- Terran Scan plus Blink Stalkers = early wall-jumping
- Vikings make fantastic escorts for Colossi or Void Rays, tearing up many of their counters

I'm sure I'm forgetting tons but my team likes to use these.

Answer (score 1):

An other technique i used with a player:

You both produce manly one unit: me mass stalker and unit upgrades / My ally mainly gling-roach.

The thing is not the tech itself but the shared control of units.
 I am better in micro than my friend, so he gives me control, and i manage both armies during the entire game.
While i manage battles, he makes sure i get reinforcement of glings /roach during the whole game and we can win easily that way.

Still, we suck at counter proxy and early ruches  :)

Comment: How does he give you control?

Comment: There is a button on the up right side of the page, just after the give ressource button