# Starcraft 2 2vs2 unit synergy

Tags: starcraft-2

What early unit combinations (specific build orders if possible) have the strong proven synergy in 2vs2 and why?

What 2vs2 strategies do pro's use and why?  We are looking for an easily executable strategy that we can begin to win games with and build on top of.  An ideal strategy would be simple to execute and require fairly low APM.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there enough synergy in different race combinations to justify a race switch when playing 2v2?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8488/is-there-enough-synergy-in-different-race-combinations-to-justify-a-race-switch-w)

Comment: Also related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/how-do-team-tactics-differ-from-1v1-tactics-in-starcraft-ii

Comment: @ Raven Hmm, I looked through both of these posted prior to posting.  I understand there are differences between 1on1 and 2on2 (your second posting) I didn't even ask about it, nor did I ask about the benefits of switching races.  I asked about proven synergy of strategies in 2on2 that are executable by two players with fairly low skill.  Perhaps my 'back story' that proceeded my question led to confusion.  Please let me know if I need to clarify my original question

Comment: @Aardvark -- ah, I forget that I'm able to see deleted posts. Tzene's answer in the first sums it up quite succinctly: "The dirty secret in esports is that 2v2 is badly broken. [The effective 2v2 strategies are all cheese] strategies that are easily countered, the entire game devolves into Rock/Paper/Scissors. My advice is: if you want to have fun, feel free to play 2v2. If you want to win, go play something else."

Comment: @Raven ah the curse of all those reputation points =D, your post did help me clarify my question.  Perhaps Tzene could help me clarify what about 2vs2 is broken and how we exploit it lol

Comment: @Raven et al. Please do not l let my personal feelings influence your decisions at all. I think a question on 2v2 is appropriate to the site and that someone could even list the "broken" strategies as answers

Comment: @Tzenes no worries, it's my fault. At any rate, even if it's not a duplicate, the linked questions *are* related.

Comment: Pros do not play 2v2 competitively, so you will have difficulty finding strategies they use. GSL, MLG, etc are all 1v1 tourneys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of strategies that can get you a quick win if the enemy fails to counter it, usually those that rely on a single unit type produced very early in high quantities. The best known examples are double 6/7/8 pools and double mass-marines from 3rax with two reactors and one tech lab for stim.

They work, they are strong, but if they don't kill both enemies fast then you are at a significant disadvantage. I do not recommend using them though.

There are a lot of combinations that work very well, but most depend on your opponents and their strategies and of course on your races. For example against two protoss going two-gate mass-zealot a Sentry/Marine force works quite well (sentries forcefield the zealots away from the marines so the marines can make use of their insane DPS) and guardian shield will also help against double mass-marine.

I do not recommend teching too fast unless the enemy turtles (for example if they have multiple cannons at the ramps). My usual 14hatch/13pool into mass-zergling/baneling strategy as Zerg is the same as my 1v1 Strategy and unless there is a 6-pool it works quite well, too.

If everything fails, try to [die slowly, as Day9 says](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/4330673/)

Comment: Generally speaking, most tier 1/1.5 unit combos can be used with good success. The strength comes from attacking one defender with both your armies before they have proper defenses.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with roach/marine.  Roaches to soak up damage and marines to deal it.  Both being ranged units it does well even against a terran wall.  We usually push out with [7 roaches](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10131/how-do-i-counter-the-7-roach-rush) and 12-15 marines.  Not sure the exact build my friend does, but I think it's 3 rax no addons.

Sometimes it wins out right, other times you do enough damage to put them economically behind (if you start pumping out workers and economy as you're pushing).

Answer (score 0):

Ones I have heard used include:

- Zerglings and Stalkers (Early Rush)
- Zerglings and Marauder
- Any combination of Heavy Ground + Heavy Air, such as Hydro + Imortals

Also see [here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/General_2v2_strategy).